# An error when I am accessing two sql tables in php

Tags: php, mysql, backend

So I am doing this thing where I was to access two tables in SQL at the same time. Basically, the system is a relief operations system where the users will be handled by batch. I was thinking of accessing the `users` table first as for the user's details and then access the `batch` table for it .However, I am stuck with this error

`Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\Relief\php\users.php on line 48`

I have a theory that the command isn't actually throwing the query to the database since it is working when I use it in the PHPMyAdmin shell. And I think I am pretty sure that was the case when I tested it using this line of code

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `batch` ;";
  $hello = $db->query($sql);
```

But I am really not sure since I don't have anything specific that is happening on my mind on what is the problem here. Thank you for the help, I am actually quite stressed out now.

users.php

```
<?php
    include("../php/databaseconnection.php");
  include("../php/dataprocessing.php");

  $request_id = $_POST["id"];
  $request_pass = $_POST["password"];
  $db = connect_on("zone83");
  $columns = take_columns($db,"users","zone83");
  
  $table = "`users`";
 
  $data = getData($table, $columns, $db, $request_id, $request_pass);

  if($data["id"] == "NO VALUE HERE"){ 


    echo'
      <script>
      alert("Wrong Credentials");
      window.location.href="../php/index.php";</script>
    ';
    exit();
  }
  
  $id = $data["id"];
  $name = $data["name"];
  $civil_status = $data["civilStatus"];
  $email = $data["email"];
  $password =$data["password"];
  $address = $data["address"];
  $contact = $data["contact"];
  $gender =  $data["gender"]; 
  $d1 = $data["dependent1"];
  $d2 = $data["dependent2"];
  $d3 = $data["dependent3"];
  $d4 = $data["dependent3"];
    $designation = $data["designation"];
  $place = $data["place"];
  $status = $data["status"];
  $db->close();
  $cv = getCivilStat($civil_status);
  $gnder = getGender($gender);
 
  //$b

  $columns = array('id', 'onPickUp', 'pickUpStart', 'pickUpEnd', 'numberOfMembers');
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `batch` ;";
  $hello = $db->query($sql);
  
  include("../html/users.html");
?>
```

dataprocessing.php

```
    <?php 
    
        function getGenderNumeral($string){
            $gnder = 0;
            switch (strtolower($string)) {
            case 'male':
                $gnder = 1;
                break;
            case 'female':
                $gnder = 2;
                break;
            case 'gay':
                $gnder = 3;
                break;
            case 'lesbian':
                $gnder = 4;
                break;
            case 'trans':
                $gnder = 5;
                break;
            case 'pan':
                $gnder = 6;
                break;
            default:
                $gnder = 10;
                break;
            }
            return $gnder;
        }
    
        function getCivilNumeral($string){
            $cv = 0;
            switch (strtolower($string)) {
            case 'single':
                $cv = 1;
                break;
            case 'married':
                $cv = 2;
                break;
            case 'widowed':
                $cv = 3;
                break;
            case 'separated':
                $cv = 4;
                break;
            default:
                $cv = 5;
                break;
            }
            return $cv;
        }
    
        function getGender($number){
            $gnder = "";
            switch ($number) {
            case 1:
              $gnder = 'Male';
              break;
            case 2:
              $gnder = 'Female';
              break;
            case 3:
              $gnder = 'Gay';
              break;
            case 4:
              $gnder = 'Lesbian';
              break;
            case 5:
              $gnder = 'Transgender';
              break;
            case 6:
              $gnder = 'Pan';
              break;
            default:
              $gnder = 'Undefined';
              break;
          }
          return $gnder;
        }
        function getCivilStat($number){
            $cv = "";
            switch ($number) {
            case 1:
              $cv = "Single";
              break;
            case 2:
              $cv = "Married";
              break;
            case 3:
              $cv = "Widowed";
              break;
            case 4:
              $cv = "Separated";
              break;
            default:
              $cv = "Undefined";
              break;
          }
          return $cv;
        }
        function getData($table,$columns, $db, $id, $pass){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table;
            $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($results);
            if($resultCheck > 0){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){     
                    if($row[$columns[0]] == $id && $row[$columns[4]] == $pass){
                        return $row;
                    }
                }
                
                return [
                            "id" => "NO VALUE HERE",
                            "name" => "NO VALUE HERE",
                            "email" => "NO VALUE HERE",
                            "civil_status" => "NO VALUE HERE",
                            "password" => "NO VALUE HERE",
                            "address" => "NO VALUE HERE",
                            "contact" => "NO VALUE HERE",
                            "gender" => "NO VALUE HERE",
                            "d1" => "NO VALUE HERE",
                            "d2" => "NO VALUE HERE",
                            "d3" => "NO VALUE HERE",
                            "d4" => "NO VALUE HERE",
                            "designation"=> "NO VALUE HERE",
                            "place"=> "NO VALUE HERE",
                        ];
            }
            
      }
    
      //the code that I'll be running if the problem is fixed
      function getDataBatch($table,$columns, $db, $id){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table;
            $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
            $data = "";
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($results);
            if($resultCheck > 0){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){     
                    if($row[$columns[0]] == $id ){
                        $data = $row;   
                    }
                }
                
            }
            return $data;
      }
?>
```

dataconnection.php
--> this is actually a script I reused from an older project

```
<?php

    function connect_on($table_name){
        $user ="root";
        $pass ="root";   //pa -change pass na lang kase root yung ginawa kong pass sa akin
        $db = $table_name; //pa-change na lang din if iba yung ginawa mong name ng databass
        $db = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die("No connections");
        return $db;
    }
    function take_columns($db, $tablename, $schema){
        echo "string";
        $sql = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '".$schema."' AND TABLE_NAME = '".$tablename."';";

        $query = $db->query($sql);
       
        while($row =$query->fetch_assoc()){
            $result[] = $row; 
        }
        $columns = array_column($result, "COLUMN_NAME");
        return $columns;
    }
   
    function error($found){
        if(!$found){
            echo("<script>alert('Wrong Credentials')</script>");
            header("Location: ../php/error.php");
            die("wrong credentilas");
        }
    }
    function form1(){
        echo "
        <div class='container'>
            <img src='../images/default/images (22).jpeg'>
            <h1>Wrong Credentials Sorry</h1>
                   
        ";
    }
    function form(){
        echo '
        <div class="container">
            <img src="../images/default/images (22).jpeg">            
            <h1>Congratulations Updated Succesfully</h1>
        ';
    }
     function draw_notice($found){
        if($found)form();
        else form1(); 
     }
     function table($columns, $db){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM guest;";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($results);
        $index = 0;
        if($resultCheck > 0){
            echo "
                <table>
                <thead>
                    <td>Number</td>
                    <td>".$columns[0]."</td>
                    <td>".$columns[1]."</td>
                    <td>".$columns[2]."</td>
                    <td>".$columns[3]."</td>
                    <td>".$columns[4]."</td>
                </thead>
            ";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
                echo "
                
                <tr>
                    <td>".++$index."</td>
                    <td>".$row[$columns[0]]."</td>
                    <td>".$row[$columns[1]]."</td>
                    <td>".$row[$columns[2]]."</td>
                    <td>".$row[$columns[3]]."</td>
                    <td>".$row[$columns[4]]."</td>
                </tr>
            ";
               
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }
        
    }


?>
```

Thank for helping I am really desperate

Comment: Maybe you close the connection to fast - `$db->close();`. Move it to the bottom.

Comment: Wtf?! HAHhahahaha thanks man! You really saved the day! Thank you for saving me huhuhuhu